# Accessing/Viewing SharePoint 2013 (On-Premise) SSRS reports from Office 365 SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

How do we access/view SSRS reports in SP 2013 (On-premise) from Office 365 SP site. Both SP sites in different domains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create and publish to a Reporting Library.

[Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283155.aspx) Microsoft's documentation on the subject.

This is just the beginning stages and if you're unaware of this there's likely a lot more configuration needed on your farm to get this operating. I would strongly suggest bringing a SharePoint Administrator on board.